# How to configure Thrift in an Angular+Electron application

Tags: angular, typescript, electron, thrift

I am trying to make Thrift api calls in my Angular application. I generated the client files using:

```bash
thrift-0.18.1.exe -r --gen js:ts <myService.thrift>
```

It generated the js and ts files and I copied them in my app. Installed thrift with `pnpm add thrift`

```js
import * as thrift from 'thrift';
import { MyServiceClient } from './myService';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class TestMyClient {
    constructor() {
        const host = 'localhost';
        const port = 45000;
        const opts = { transport: thrift.TBufferedTransport, protocol: thrift.TJSONProtocol, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.apache.thrift.json', }, https: true, path: '/url/path', useCORS: true, };

        const connection = thrift.createXHRConnection(host, port, opts);
        const thriftClient = thrift.createXHRClient(MyServiceClient, connection);

        connection.on('error', (err) => { console.error(err); });

        const data = thriftClient.myAPI();
        console.log(`data received: ${data}`);
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

```bash
Uncaught ReferenceError: myService_myAPI_args is not defined
```

It seems to be thrown by webpack while bundling the generated client files. Am I missing something here? Do I need to add some more configuration?

Comment: To my understanding `thrift` has a nodejs client. I don't think it will work on a browser. Electron part should be using the thrift and you need to exchange the data over `IPCRenderer`.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your code as shown below

```
import * as thrift from 'thrift';
import { MyServiceClient } from './myService';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()    
export class TestMyClient {    
    constructor() {    
        const host = 'localhost';    
        const port = 45000;    
        const opts = {     
            transport: thrift.TBufferedTransport,     
            protocol: thrift.TJSONProtocol,     
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.apache.thrift.json' }, 
            https: true, 
            path: '/url/path', 
            useCORS: true
        };

        const connection = thrift.createXHRConnection(host, port, opts);
        const thriftClient = thrift.createXHRClient(MyServiceClient, connection);

        connection.on('error', (err) => { console.error(err); });

        const args = {};    
        args.myParam = 'my value'; // set any required arguments on the args object

        thriftClient.myAPI(args, (err, response) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
            } else {
                console.log(`data received: ${response}`);
            }
        });
    }
}
```